# From SQL to Neo4j: trying to group query results

Tags: sql, database, oracle, neo4j, cypher

I have the following query in SQL (**Oracle DB 11g XE**)

**Just for context**: this query search the sensor with the biggest Power Factor, in a range between 0.90 and 0.99, for each month)

```
with abc as (select extract(month from peak_time) as Month, 
max(total_power_factor) as Max_Power_Factor 
from sensors group by extract(month from peak_time) order by Month DESC) 
select abc.Month, Max_Power_Factor, meter_id as "Made by" 
from abc join sensors 
on sensors.total_power_factor = abc.Max_Power_Factor 
where Max_Power_Factor between 0.90 and 0.99
order by Max_Power_Factor;
```

SQL Developer show me the correct result, only **ONE line for each month**, without duplicates; for example:

```
Month  Max_Power_Factor Scored by
6      0.981046427565   b492b271760a
1      0.945921825336   db71ffead179
3      0.943302142482   a9c471b03587
8      0.9383185638     410bd58c8396
7      0.930911694091   fe5954a46888
5      0.912872055549   ee3c8ec29155
```

My problem is trying to *replicate the same query* on **Neo4j** (3.2.1 CE, on Windows 10): I don't know exactly how to group the data in order to have the same results. (As you can see I'm using *APOC* to manage dates)

```
match(a:Sensor) with a, a.peak_time as peak_time
where (a.total_power_factor > 0.90 and a.total_power_factor <0.99 )
RETURN distinct a.meterid, max(peak_time),apoc.date.format(peak_time,'s','MM') as month
order by month desc
```

These are my Cypher results and, as you can see, **there are multiple row for each month**.

```
Month   Max_Power_Factor Scored by
06      0.981046427565  b492b271760a
01      0.945921825336  db71ffead179
03      0.943302142482  a9c471b03587
08      0.9383185638    410bd58c8396
08      0.93451098613   dfd6b67cc6d6
07      0.930911694091  fe5954a46888
02      0.916440282713  649956b34e87
05      0.912872055549  ee3c8ec29155
08      0.907059974935  a3e8df8a0ba8
```

So my question is: **How can I group the data in order to have the same ouput as Oracle DB?** (If it's possible, of course)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fields in the output you show do not correspond to the query (for example, what exactly is "Scored By" ?) but the trick to aggregating in Neo4j is understanding that the aggregation keys are implicit.

So if you have

```
RETURN distinct a.meterid, max(peak_time),apoc.date.format(peak_time,'s','MM') as month
```

you are grouping on **meterid and month**.

If you want to group on month only it should be

```
RETURN max(peak_time),apoc.date.format(peak_time,'s','MM') as month
```

Hope this helps !

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Yes, I made a bit of confusion posting data names here but thank you so much, your solution was perfect! Thanks again!